# Facebook comments widget

Tags: .net, facebook, widget, comments

I am using facebook comments widget, when a user posts a comment it also appears on his facebook account's wall, but i want it to be appear in my website facebook account's wall too. I have tried many ways but no success.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the functionality you are requesting doesn't appear to be available on the social plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

**Attributes**

- href - the URL for this Comments plugin. News feed stories on Facebook will link to this URL.
- width - the width of the plugin in pixels. Minimum recommended width: 400px.
- colorscheme - the color scheme for the plugin. Options: 'light', 'dark'
- num_posts - the number of comments to show by default. Default: 10. Minimum: 1
- mobile - whether to show the mobile-optimized version. Default: auto-detect.

As you can see, there's not one there.

To get your desired functionality, you will need to develop your own facebook comments widget/app to use on your website(s).  Please see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ for how to get started.